# Discord js two arguments

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, arguments

I'd like to add two argument options to my bot.

First - join date on the server less than X

Second - account creation date younger than X

````
    let memberCount = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 1000*60*60*24*10 && Date.now() - member.joinedAt < 1000*60*60*24*1).size;
const Members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 1000*60*60*24*10 && Date.now() - member.joinedAt < 1000*60*60*24*1).map(member => "<@"+member.user.id+">");
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/g);
switch(args[0]){
    case 'szukaj':
    message.channel.send("```Konta młodsze niż 10 dni i czas na serwerze krótszy niż 1 dzień.```**Ilość:** "+memberCount+"").then;
    if(Members == 0)
        message.channel.send("**Nie znaleziono nic! Jest czyściutko szefuniu.** ");
    if (Members >= 1)
        console.log(`\n${Members}`);
        message.channel.send(`\n${Members}`);
        break;
````

But how to add two arguments after SZUKAJ? (szukaj = search)

**Example:**

`szukaj 1d 10d

Found:<here bot show all accounts who join less than 1d and account creation date younger than 10d>

**Example2:**

`szukaj 2h 7h

Found:<here bot show all accounts who join less than 2h and account creation date younger than 7d>

**Example3:**

`szukaj 2h 0

Found:<here bot show all accounts who join less than 2h>

**Example4:**

`szukaj 0 7h

Found:<here bot show all accounts creation date younger than 7d>

It's possible to add two time arguments? First **member.joinedAt** and second **member.user.createdAt**.

Comment: args[0] - its first argument args[1] its 2 argument.

Comment: So, how to define args[0] = member.joinedAt<[args 0 in time] and args[1] =member.user.createdAt<[args 1 in time]?